# javascript plugin/form similar to google calendar repeat options

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-calendar-api

Is there a javascript plugin which replicates the same functionality as google calendar repeat options visually?

[image: Google calendar repeat options]

Comment: I personally don't see why this was closed.... I think that the front end UI for something like this can be totally separate from the back end.... and why should everyone have to rebuild the wheel? and for what it's worth, the best one i've found so far is here: https://github.com/collective/jquery.recurrenceinput.js or here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/8490819/26510

Comment: and for those (like myself) that are searching for solutions to this, note that alot of robust solutions for this are centered around the following RFC for calendar events: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545 so searching for that rfc will give you some good links too... Note that the JS library mentioned above (https://github.com/collective/jquery.recurrenceinput.js) works with this RFC/iCal format.

Comment: i see that others are also referencing this RFC as well: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt

Comment: This is a relevant programming topic IMHO. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you are looking for (the UI is a bit different), but there is a extension of the full calendar plugin that supports recurring events. See the demo here : http://fullcalendar.vinsol.com/

Note that the code is Ruby on Rails.

I think you might have a hard time finding a purely javascript plugin for that feature, mainly because although it isn't essential, it kind of requires some sort of database / backend code to deal with the occurences. Pure javascript solutions for a problem like recurring events will most likely be a bit hacky.

The [Full Calendar Control](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) is a great javascript control, which is easily extensible. If you have something like it running, then adding the recurring event screen really shouldn't be that big of a deal. Most calendar controls out there will already pop a window when you create an event. The markup / js for the screenshot in your question really won't be hard to write. The backend code is where you'll end up doing most of your work I think, and jQuery plugins won't help you with that.