# google calendar ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to use google calandar api to display events that are not from a google account ?
actually I have a website with bookings (start date, end date so like a google calandar event) for offers (like a room), I want to display the bookings of an offer, so I think it could be cool if I can provide my db data to fill the agenda (with all the agenda feature). but I'm not sure it is the purpose of the google calandar api

If not, is it possible to find something that do the same (display events, add events etc via ajax) in a kind of jquery lib ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are some :

- http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/10/jquery-calendar-date-pickers.html
- http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins/
- http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/
- http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure I know what you're asking here, but [might jQuery FullCalendar be what you're looking for](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)?

Comment: @tahir: In that case I'm still not sure what you're asking.

Comment: asking if it is possible to use google calandar system of building events, displaying events on a calandar, recurring events etc. but the data are not provided by a google account, but by my database (fetched via json for example)

Comment: @tahir: You can [subscribe to iCal calendars in google calendar](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=37100). So if you publish your data in an iCal format, then you will be able to display it inside a google calendar, if that's what you're after.